# Как взять имя нового установленого приложения в IPhone

Tags: swift

Хочу в background взять имя нового установленного приложения. На ум приходит только фреймворк IHasapp но он устаревший и неподерживаемый. Читаю доку  не могу понять как мне это сделать [cылка](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) . Хотя бы взять имя(нового установленного приложения)!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без JB никак.

До iOS 8 это можно было сделать прочитав `com.apple.mobile.installation.plist` (необходим JB), но начиная с iOS 8 он отсутствует. Можете глянуть [данный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226406/get-list-of-all-installed-apps)

Для получения приложений на iOS 8+ можете глянуть эти решения: [MobileInstallationLookup-for-ios8](https://github.com/peter158/MobileInstallationLookup-for-ios8-) и [AppList](https://github.com/rpetrich/AppList)

И снова же, нужен JB.

Answer (score 1):

iHasApp не просто так заброшен, а [в связи с отклонениями в App Store из-за его применения](https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp/issues/34).

В Apple сочли, что это использование недокументированных особенностей API и противоречит пункту 3.3.1 из "iOS Developer Program License Agreement". [Вот их комментарий](https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp#statement-from-apple):

> We also found that your app uses public APIs in a manner not prescribed by Apple, which is not in compliance with the iOS Developer Program License Agreement, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> In particular, section 3.3.1 of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement specifies:
>
> > *Applications may only use Documented APIs in the manner prescribed by Apple and must not use or call any private APIs*
>
> Specifically, we found this app misuses "canOpenURL:" to extrapolate which apps are installed on a device.

По всей видимости, Apple против того, чтобы отдельное приложение могло узнавать, как приложения установлены на устройстве (а то, что вы хотите сделать, именно это и позволяет). Так что даже если техническая возможность есть, это с большой вероятностью не пройдёт ревью в App Store.

*Хотя в тех редких случаях, когда одобрение App Store не волнует, способ iHasApp, вероятно, ещё работает.*